# Java - convert word to pdf directly in AWS S3 bucket without having to download locally

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am wondering if i can convert a word document to pdf document directly in the AWS S3 bucket meaning without having to download on my local drive...

I tried using the BytesArrayOutputStream without any luck..

thx

Comment: You may want to read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 is for Storage of content and does not support converting files such as Word to PDF. To convert a WORD doc to PDF, you need to use a 3rd party lib such as https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-convert-docx-to-pdf-in-java. Once you convert the file, you can store the converted file in an Amazon S3 bucket.

Comment: I am able to convert but only if i used local file path, i am trying to avoid that by having everything on s3

Comment: What API are you using to convert ?

Comment: Currently using IConverter but i have tried other such as Docx4J but the issue is having to do it without copying locally.

Comment: You can look at writing a Lambda function that is invoked when you drop the file into an Amazon S3 bucket.

Comment: my converWordToPDF is a lambda function but i will check it out as soon i drop a file if he can convert it... thank for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Amazons s3 bucket is used for only storage purpose , you can convert word to pdf using any third party lib .. apache poi ,once the file is converted to pdf , then you need to upload in to s3 bucket

Answer (score 0):

AWS recently released a possibility to execute custom transformation code in the GET of any S3 object from lambda.

In short... Every time someone does a GET in your pdf, your lambda would take the object and transform it before delivering it to the client.

Links:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/transforming-objects.html
https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/aws/introducing-amazon-s3-object-lambda-use-your-code-to-process-data-as-it-is-being-retrieved-from-s3/